# how do I reuse VALUE= html form

Tags: types

Can something like the persons name be reused later in the form?

```
<p>Question 1.) Name:<input type="text" name="Applicant_Name" /></p>




<p>Question 45.) Re-type your name: <input type="????" value="Applicant_Name" /></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to reuse the text entered in a text field, for the purpose of populating to other text field(s). You need little bit of `javascript` with your `HTML` like bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <script type = "text/javascript">
       function myFunction(currElement, idOflname){
          var x=document.getElementById(idOflname);
          x.value=currElement.value;
       }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <form action="yourAction">
        Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup='myFunction(this, "lname")'><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can write a javascript function (here, `myFunction`) which will put the content of first text field to second one. And you need to call this function in the `onkeyup` of the first text field.

Hope this answers your problem!

Comment: @NathanGaston nice to hear... :)